# How do I Open Samsung's .sme files?

Tags: backup, kies

I have a Samsung mobile phone, and I was using  the software that came along with it (Samsung Kies) to backup all my SMS's on my desktop.

This software creates a `.sme` file, to store the backup.

I was wondering if there is any other software that can open these files, or I am stuck with a proprietary data format.

Comment: It may be just text - try opening in notepad.

Comment: @Paul: Na.. doesn't work

Comment: **How is this off topic? It clearly is a desktop computer question about reading a specific file firmat.**

Comment: Have you tried unzipping it...

Answer (score 1):

I've not used Kies (for an Android phone?) myself, but there are alternatives if you want to read your text messages on a PC.
There are some SMS backup / restore apps in the Android Market that will create a standard XML file on the SD card.

Comment: Unfortunately, It's not an Android Phone.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://www.samsungwaveforum.com/samsung-wave-discussions/contacts-and-sms-read-sme-and-spb-files/?wap2). It looks like the only way to read it is through Kies.

Comment: The topic that link was pointing to seems to be gone.

Answer (score 0):

The simple thing you have to do is just install Mobogenie Android PC suite. Restore your SMS and other application data from Samsung Kies to your phone, and then close Samsung Kies.

Open Mobogenie and enable "USB DEBUG", then select "manage my phone from Mobogenie PC Suite" and create a back-up file which will run and transferable on all Androids.

Now connect the Android device where you want to restore your all data... and you are done! It is only possible when your use Mobogenie PC suite because Samsung Kies has no option to convert the `.sme` files into `.xml`, `.csv` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Samsung Galaxy Previal and have loaded the app 'SMS to Text' by SMeiTi. It pulls my messages and exports them to email as a txt, cvs, xlsx or html file. Or I've saved it on the phone as a txt file and used my text editor.

Answer (score 0):

After unsuccessful searching for SME-to-anything converter, I installed mobile app SMStoText - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smeiti.smstotext and exported all SMS messages in the phone. The app supports txt and csv format.
Note that even the choice is named "Export to SD card", you have to search result file in `Device storage` rather than `SD memory card` directory (the actual place is `/storage/emulated/0/SMStoText`)