# Opening a Samsung Kies .SME file on PC Without Access to Samsung Phone

Tags: android

I have searched high and low for an answer to my question.

I backed up some SMS files, using Samsung Kies, I no longer have a Samsung device (hence can't restore it, etc.) but need the data from within these messages. Is there anyway to open/convert/view them on my PC? I have a .SME file and an XML that just contains info about the .SME file. I looked in Kies as some people across Google say you can open them, but I can't find an option for the life of me?

I did search and find an [old post on here](https://superuser.com/questions/360540/how-do-i-open-samsungs-sme-files) but the links were dead, and most of it was irrelevant, so I hope you don't mind me posting.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Open Samsung's .sme files?](http://superuser.com/questions/360540/how-do-i-open-samsungs-sme-files)

Comment: Not true, like I said I no longer have the phone and the one useful link in that thread is dead.

Comment: But that doesn't make it a different question. If you'd like newer/different answers, please consider [earning some rep](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) and posting [a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on the exiting question instead of repeating it.

Comment: It *is* a different question because that question is for when you still have the Samsung phone, and this one is for when you don't.

Answer (score -1):

Hey there hope this helps, when you open Kies and export your Messages(I'm just gunna go ahead and assume you know how to do this already :P), when it prompts you to choose a File Location and Name, change the file type from .sme to .html. You should then be able to open it with your browser, Didn't try it on firefox but if it doesn't I had no issues with Microsoft Edge (its was the first recommended app to open with).

Good luck, Cheers!

Comment: And presumably if they have already backed it up, changing the file extension would work. If this wasn't a old question, I'd probably have asked up to try a file identification tool like TRID on the file first to confirm its a html file with a different extension